# Color RGB to html color value

Tags: vba, colors

I want to get the hexadecimal value of a Color. The problem is that in vba the value .Font.Color.RGB comes in decimal and when I change that value to hexadecimal I don't get the value that I need.

For example:

The value color blue violet is 14822282 in vba.
In html the value is #8A2BE2
But when I use Hex(14822282) method I get E22B8A.

How is possible to get the proper number?

Comment: See the answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/626a351a-de17-4389-9ad6-a2be20ce2fd9/convert-contents-of-a-formatted-excel-cell-to-html-format?forum=isvvba  Basically you just need to re-arrange the hex value a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim hexCode

    hexCode = Hex(14822282)

    For Index = 1 To Len(hexCode)
        If InStr("01234567890ABCDEF", Mid$(hexCode, Index, 1)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Not a valid hex color code"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    If Len(hexCode) = 6 Then _
    Debug.Print "&H00" & Right(hexCode, 2) & _
    Mid$(hexCode, 3, 2) & Left(hexCode, 2) & "&"
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because you need to split that decimal value into 3 components (R, G, B) using bitwise operations, then convert each component into hex separately. You can then concatenate the hex values together and that will get you your HTML hex value.

Here's an example:

To get the Green component, you'd do a bit shift like this:

```
14822282 >> 8
```

Only take the byte value and convert it to hex, which will give you 0x2B, which is the G component of RGB.

To get the Red component, shift 16 bits to the right:

```
14822282 >> 16
```

This will give you 0xE2 in hex.

To get the blue component, lob off all bits except the far 8 bits to the right. You'll get 0x8A.

That is what gets you #E22B8A.